# how to display a specific content on selected option | jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i've this code where i have a specific div i want to show if i selected a specific option

my code is based on this codepen tutorial: https://codepen.io/scanfcode/pen/vZJmQo

however it does not working

```js
$('#select_service').change(function() {
  var select = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
  console.log(select);

  $(".hide").hide();
  $('#' + select).show();
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Layanan yang Digunakan</label>
  <select class="custom-select" id="select_service" name="service">
    <option value="0" disabled>Pilih:</option>
    <option value="FIFASTRA">FIFASTRA</option>
    <option value="SPEKTRA">SPEKTRA</option>
    <option value="DANASTRA">DANASTRA</option>
    <option value="AMITRA">AMITRA</option>
    <option value="FINATRA">FINATRA</option>
    <option value="FLEET">FLEET</option>
  </select>
</div>

<br> //content i want to show based on value
<div class="form-group hide" id="SPEKTRA">
  <label>Pilih Jenis Pembiayaan</label>
  <select class="custom-select" name="type">
    <option value="Pembiayaan Elektronik">Pembiayaan Elektronik</option>
    <option value="Pembiayaan Furniture">Pembiayaan Furniture</option>
    <option value="Pembiayaan Gadget">Pembiayaan Gadget</option>
  </select>
  <span class="message" id="type"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group hide" id="DANASTRA">
  <label>Pilih Jenis Pembiayaan</label>
  <select class="custom-select" name="type">
    <option value="Pembiayaan Multiguna" selected>Pembiayaan Multiguna</option>
  </select>
  <span class="message" id="type"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group hide" id="FIFASTRA">
  <label>Pilih Jenis Pembiayaan</label>
  <select class="custom-select" name="type">
    <option value="Pembiayaan Motor Honda" selected>Pembiayaan Motor Honda</option>
  </select>
  <span class="message" id="type"></span>
</div>


<div class="form-group hide" id="FINATRA">
  <label>Pilih Jenis Pembiayaan</label>
  <select class="custom-select" name="type">
    <option value="Pembiayaan Produktif Usaha Mikro" selected>Pembiayaan Produktif Usaha Mikro</option>
  </select>
  <span class="message" id="type"></span>
</div>


<div class="form-group hide" id="FLEET">
  <label>Pilih Jenis Pembiayaan</label>
  <select class="custom-select" name="type">
    <option value="Pembiayaan Group Customer">Pembiayaan Group Customer</option>
    <option value="Pembiayaan Corporate Operational">Pembiayaan Corporate Operational</option>
    <option value="Pembiayaan Employee Benefit">Pembiayaan Employee Benefit</option>
  </select>
  <span class="message" id="type"></span>
</div>
```

in the snippet it's showing an error, but on my console in my code it's not returning any error

[the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IO7dU.png)

it should be showing on the right side of this option (image above)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code. did you get the result from `console.log(select)` ?

Comment: @AbuZubair i know, right? i got the value from what i've selected (e.g: FIFASTRA, DANASTRA)

Comment: did you inspect in browser devtool and check whether selected div is updating the element (html/css) whenever you select from `select_service` ?

Comment: the error in the snippet came from the missing jquery library. iadded it now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to remove the `change()` statement at the end of your `change` event listener. To initially hide the divs you could simply use the following line from your event handler:

```js
$(".hide").hide();
```

**Working example**

```js
$('#select_service').change(function() {
  var select = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
  console.log(select);

  $(".hide").hide();
  $('#' + select).show();
});

$(".hide").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Layanan yang Digunakan</label>
  
  <select class="custom-select" id="select_service" name="service">
    <option value="0" disabled>Pilih:</option>
    <option value="FIFASTRA">FIFASTRA</option>
    <option value="SPEKTRA">SPEKTRA</option>
    <option value="DANASTRA">DANASTRA</option>
    <option value="AMITRA">AMITRA</option>
    <option value="FINATRA">FINATRA</option>
    <option value="FLEET">FLEET</option>
  </select>
</div>

<br> //content i want to show based on value
<div class="form-group hide" id="SPEKTRA">
  <label>Pilih Jenis Pembiayaan</label>
  
  <select class="custom-select" name="type">
    <option value="Pembiayaan Elektronik">Pembiayaan Elektronik</option>
    <option value="Pembiayaan Furniture">Pembiayaan Furniture</option>
    <option value="Pembiayaan Gadget">Pembiayaan Gadget</option>
  </select>
  
  <span class="message" id="type"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group hide" id="DANASTRA">
  <label>Pilih Jenis Pembiayaan</label>
  
  <select class="custom-select" name="type">
    <option value="Pembiayaan Multiguna" selected>Pembiayaan Multiguna</option>
  </select>
  
  <span class="message" id="type"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group hide" id="FIFASTRA">
  <label>Pilih Jenis Pembiayaan</label>
  
  <select class="custom-select" name="type">
    <option value="Pembiayaan Motor Honda" selected>Pembiayaan Motor Honda</option>
  </select>
  
  <span class="message" id="type"></span>
</div>


<div class="form-group hide" id="FINATRA">
  <label>Pilih Jenis Pembiayaan</label>
  
  <select class="custom-select" name="type">
    <option value="Pembiayaan Produktif Usaha Mikro" selected>Pembiayaan Produktif Usaha Mikro</option>
  </select>
  
  <span class="message" id="type"></span>
</div>


<div class="form-group hide" id="FLEET">
  <label>Pilih Jenis Pembiayaan</label>
  
  <select class="custom-select" name="type">
    <option value="Pembiayaan Group Customer">Pembiayaan Group Customer</option>
    <option value="Pembiayaan Corporate Operational">Pembiayaan Corporate Operational</option>
    <option value="Pembiayaan Employee Benefit">Pembiayaan Employee Benefit</option>
  </select>
  
  <span class="message" id="type"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! finally found where i was wrong! thank you!